# How to send SOAP fault when max orders reached?

Tags: soap, tibco

I am designing order management process, and struck up at to configure SOAP fault when maximum messages reached. Is it possible to configure Hawk rulebase and then send SOAP fault?

Answer (score 0):

SOAP faults should not be sent through hawk rulebases. Hawk rulebases are not meant to implement any business logic. So, SOAP fault should be sent from the business process itself. The solution will depend on the exact requirements.